# What is the difference between the transition kernel and the proposal density?

Tags: markov-process, metropolis-hastings

When considering MCMC, could someone explain the difference between the transition kernel and the porposal density for me please?

Proposal density is the function we use to sample from the proposal distribution to generate a candidate value for the target density in the MH algorithm.

Transition kernel is a conditional density that relates how we move to $x_{t+1}$ from $x_t$

I have been unable to discern between the transition kernel and the proposal density and would love an explanation please

Thank you

Comment: You can use x_{t+1} to get the correct subscript.

Comment: Hi: Page 415 of the paper at the link below explains what they are. But I would read the whole thing start to finish.  When I was learning the MCMC material, I remember it being the clearest thing I found for understanding all of the gory details. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fa40/c89cca57fd9ddeb62212de2abb248f39737d.pdf?_ga=2.259175498.1919301652.1582894764-1280865350.1551495286